# update 20M records in table and set col1 = col2 + col3 for each record using spring boot

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, query-optimization

update 20M records in table and set col1 = col2 + col3 for each record using spring boot.

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            String updateQuery = "UPDATE table SET col1 = ? WHERE id = ?";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

        for (TableEntity entity : tableEntities) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, calculate(offersLeadScore)); // Set new col1
            preparedStatement.setObject(2, entity.getId());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();`
```

The above approach is taking so much time to execute and update all records in table.

How to achieve faster execution using spring boot?

Tried JPA's saveAll() and above approach. Could not optimise it.

Need some industry standard approach to update all records in one table in faster way.

Comment: It seems to me that this question doesn't satisfy criteria of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You mention col2+col3 in the title but it never plays any role in the code. The code mentions some objects and functions that are not introduced above. Please get rid of unimportant details in your example code so that it's possible to suggest something.

Comment: Also, from the first sight, I don't think this problem has something to do with Spring. Spring only gives you convenient way to get rid of boiler plate code and configuration. Optimising batch update for 20 mln records is not what Spring is invented for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it works by using a Spring Boot service called TableService to effectively update a big dataset of 20 million records inside a database table. The updateCol1ForTable function contains the main operation. This method builds a SQL update query that, using the record's id as a reference, computes the new value for col1 as the sum of col2 and col3 for each record.
Here is the code;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TableService {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public TableService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void updateCol1ForTable(List<TableEntity> tableEntities) {
        String updateQuery = "UPDATE your_table_name SET col1 = col2 + col3 WHERE id = ?";
        
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
                preparedStatement.setLong(1, tableEntities.get(i).getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return tableEntities.size();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To efficiently update the records in batches, call this function from your service layer or controller.

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Why? At best you are introducing a maintenance headache. Will every developer and user remember to appropriately update `col1` whenever col2 and/or col3 is updated and every time a row is inserted. A much better solution is to perform the calculation on the `select`. It is a 1 time maintenance of the select. If for some reason you think you need to store the derived result then define `col1` as a generated. First drop the column then re-add it: ([demo here)](https://dbfiddle.uk/to2AVMtH)

```
alter table <your_table_name> drop col1; 
alter table <your_table_name> 
      add col1 bigint
          generated always as (col2::bigint + col3::bigint) stored;
```

The initial run/setting will not be fast. But the trade off is you have no maintenance and the value of `col1` is automatically calculated when a row is added and whenever `col2' and/or` col3' is updated. No additional maintenance required initially or later.

Comment: what if we dont want to update col1 based on some condition? like if col1 is greater than 100, dont update it. But update remaining. (just an example)

Comment: Then using a generated column will not work. It seems you have 3 viable choices. 1: A trigger which performs the calculation when needed. 2: Create a view which derives the appropriate value. 3: Just derive it during SELECT. ( a first step for the view). 4: Leave it to the app (viable only if you can guarantee the app is the only access - I never figured out how to do that. ). Without knowing all the details I would tend for #2.